# Accessing 3+ SD/MMC /dev/mmcblk devices

Tags: pi-3, sd-card, spi, driver, device-tree

I've successfully followed some instructions for access 2 SD cards via SPI on a Raspberry Pi 3: https://ralimtek.com/Raspberry_Pi_Secondary_SD_Card/

How do I configure it to access more than 2 SD cards?

DTS file from that article:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
   compatible = "brcm,bcm2835", "brcm,bcm2836", "brcm,bcm2708", "brcm,bcm2709";

   fragment@0 {
      target = <&spi0>;
      frag0: __overlay__ {
         status = "okay";
         sd1 {
                reg = <0>;
                status = "okay";
                compatible = "spi,mmc_spi";
                voltage-ranges = <3000 3500>;
                spi-max-frequency = <8000000>;
         };
         sd2 {
                reg = <1>;
                status = "okay";
                compatible = "spi,mmc_spi";
                voltage-ranges = <3000 3500>;
                spi-max-frequency = <8000000>;
         };

      };
   };


};
```

Comment: By configuring the chip selects, I can access the mounted SD partitions simultaneously.  For instance, I could cp files from one drive to another and the OS would handle all of the channel select switching.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible to configure SD3 and SD4 via device trees alone.  Even modifying a driver would be helpful.